# A Simpler way of Thinking About Integrability

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system

I have recently been looking into the concept of integrability with regard to dynamical systems, and the more I look into it, the less sense it seems to make. There seems to be several kinds of integrability and their definitions tend to be quite dense and technical. On a very high level, what does it mean for a system to be integrable? Was integrability an old concept which took a lot of work to rigorously define? Are there any text books which give a good intuitive grasp of integrablilty? If it helps I'm working with Hamiltonian dynamical systems.

Comment: Your _last_ sentence totally changes the flavor of your posting.  Before seeing that and your tags, I thought you were talking about something completely different from what it now appears your question is about. $\qquad$

Comment: How so? My whole intention was to ask a question about integrable systems (maybe I should have put those words in there). Where was the miscommunication so I can edit my post?

Comment: "Integrability" means different things in different contexts.  In the context of dynamical systems (not mentioned until the end) you wouldn't mean the same thing that you'd be talking about if you meant something like Lebesgue integrability or Riemann integrability or something like that. If you put your last sentence first, then it would clear those other topics out of the way at the outset. $\qquad$

Comment: I see now that the question was quite ambiguous. It's been a while since I've thought about measure theory so I didn't think of that. Thanks!

Comment: On a high level, being integrable means that you can give a complete set of explicit solutions. The connection to integration of functions is that the integral $\phi(x)=\int f(x)\,dx$ is the solution to the differential equation $\phi'(x) = f(x)$.